# I'm trying to make a post request with headers but when I send request then return a bad request error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, redux, axios

I'm trying to make a post request with headers but when I send request then return a bad request error.

```
const header = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN
    }
}

export const postProductAsync = createAsyncThunk("products/postProductAsync", async (data) => {
    const res = await axios.post(GET_CATEGORIES, data, header);
    return await res.data;
})
```

Also I'm using fileBase64 I think this could be the problem

```
<FileBase64 multiple={false} onDone={({base64}) => setFile(base64)} className="input" />
```

Comment: What you've called `header` there is more properly called a [request config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config). It looks okay. What makes you think axios isn't sending it? What do you see in the Network panel of devtools?

Comment: Side note: Obviously, when writing code for yourself, you can use any indentation/bracing style you like, but when writing code for others to read and understand (such as in a question), please use one of the standard styles that indents each level, doesn't hide closing `}` at the end of previous statements/data, etc. I've updated the code in the question for you.